# Package installation in Julia

Tags: package, julia

I tried to use the (very highly recommended) **Eirine** package in Julia. Adding it seems to work fine, but `using Eirine` blows up in my face as below. This happens on both Windows and Linux, and the Julia version 1.1, just as in the `Eirine` documentation. Any suggestions will be welcome.

```
julia> using Eirene
[ Info: Precompiling Eirene [9c0f25c4-2ca1-5870-89f6-52640788da1d]
┌ Warning: Package Eirene does not have Pkg in its dependencies:
│ - If you have Eirene checked out for development and have
│   added Pkg as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
│   environment's manifest file, try `Pkg.resolve()`.
│ - Otherwise you may need to report an issue with Eirene
└ Loading Pkg into Eirene from project dependency, future warnings for 
Eirene ar                    e suppressed.
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: KeyError: key "Plotly" not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Dict{String,Union{Nothing, VersionNumber}}, ::String) at 
./dict.                    jl:478
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [5] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [6] include(::String) at 
 /home/rivin/.julia/packages/Plotly/C5oqo/src/Plotly.jl                    
:1
 [7] top-level scope at none:0
 [8] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [10] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [11] top-level scope at none:2
 [12] eval at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [13] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:404
 [14] top-level scope at ./none:3
 in expression starting at 
/home/rivin/.julia/packages/Plotly/C5oqo/src/v2.jl:6
in expression starting at 
/home/rivin/.julia/packages/Plotly/C5oqo/src/Plotly.jl                    
:19
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Plotly [58dd65bb-95f3-509e-9936- 
c39a10fde                    ae7] to 
/home/rivin/.julia/compiled/v1.1/Plotly/M5iCk.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1197
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
 [6] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [9] top-level scope at none:2
 [10] eval at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [11] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:404
 [12] top-level scope at ./none:3
 in expression starting at 
 /home/rivin/.julia/packages/Eirene/QIFsh/src/Eirene.jl                    
 :42
 ERROR: Failed to precompile Eirene [9c0f25c4-2ca1-5870-89f6-52640788da1d] to 
 /ho                    me/rivin/.julia/compiled/v1.1/Eirene/mCiG1.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1197
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853

julia>
```

Comment: have you tried installing plotly?

Comment: @OscarSmith Truly you are wise in the ways of science! I was laboring under the misconception that a dependency would be handled automatically...

Comment: It should, not sure why it wasn't, but that was my guess from reading the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, it seems `plotly` which this depends upon was not installed correctly. Manually installing should fix it.